# Stop deploying a webapp in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Can we stop deploying of one specific webapp from deploying in tomcat when starting the server?

I am developing customized tomcat and I don't want some web apps deployed according to the conditions from a configuration file.

Comment: You can always just delete the exploded folder and rename the WAR file to something other than `.WAR`.  This is what I usually do.  Not pretty, but it works.  If you have a long term need for this, then I would question why you have the webapp deployed in the first place.

Comment: My requirement is "We have different profiles for our server, We need to undeploy some webapps as they are not needed for that profile"

Comment: You can always write a batch script which automates what I described.  If Tomcat sees neither exploded nor archive WAR, it can't run it.

Comment: Look at the [Host documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment) particularly at the _deployIgnore_ setting.